# Should I award bounty

Tags: discussion, bounties

Hi I put bounty on someone else's question.

[How to compile a svn python binding for windows from the source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894744/how-to-compile-a-svn-python-binding-for-windows-from-the-source)

I've answered it (using a google search) and so has someone else. I can't get my answer to work and his/her answer doesn't apply to me. (though it may do to the origional asker), my answer is higher voted.

Should I award the bounty to them?

Wes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bounty is for *your* benefit; if it was important enough to the person who asked the question then he or she would have started his/her *own* bounty and awarded it to whichever answer was acceptable to *them*.

Award the bounty to whichever answer is most useful to *you*.  That's the idea.  Just keep in mind that you won't get any points if you award it to yourself.

Comment: Ugh. More people using "points" or... *gasp* "exp" instead of "reputation".

Comment: hey, I am all about the "points"

Comment: @Hello: I always refer to it as "reputation" when I'm referring to the number itself.  When referring to a gain or loss, I use the terms "rep points" or just "points" interchangeably.  I don't really see the problem.